# How can i share bitmap in facebook in android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my app sharing bitmap to facebook .Link,description,message and imageurl all posting the facebook well but bitmap not share to facebook.
I am using the following code:

```
Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),   R.drawable.ic_launcher);
          ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
    byte[]      data = baos.toByteArray();



if ( friend_uid != null ) {
                   final Activity activity = SocialSharingActivity.this;
                   Bundle params = new Bundle();
                   params.putString("name", "pictabsample");
                   params.putByteArray("picture",data);
////                   params.pu
                   params.putString("to", friend_uid);
//                 
                   WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(SocialSharingActivity.this, Session.getActiveSession(), params))
                           .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                    FacebookException error) {

                            }}).build();
                   feedDialog.show();
               }
```

where i done mistake didn't findout.please tell me anyone known advance thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

May be you should not transfer bitmap data to SocialSharingActivity

params.putString("path",picturePath);

Comment: i have bitmap how to path of string

Comment: you should save the bitmap to native